# Display TableView<ObservableList<String>> inside TreeView<E>

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, treetableview

The design I had in mind is something like this:
There's a `TreeView<E>`, where `E` is a wrapper class which implementation could look like this:

```
public class E {
    private int key;
    private String value;

    public E(int key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getKey(){
        return key; 
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

So `TreeView<E>` will contain a bunch of `TreeItem<E>` instances. And the `toString()` method of `E` displays the value.

And when you press any of the tree items, I want a `TableView<ObservableList<String>>` to be shown below the selected `TreeItem<E>` containing all rows from a DB that is connected to the key value of the `TreeItem<E>`.

Is this possible? I know `TreeTableView` is a decent option, but I don't want to show any columns unless I do press one of the tree items. And I want each `TreeItem<E>` to have its own table. Although, for the record, all tables will have the same columns, just a different amount of rows.

**Update:
With the help of @Uluk Biy I've managed to implement a solution, but it contains one bug.**

The problem is that when I press a TreeItem in the TreeView, the node that gets selected is the node that is two steps below the first node that isn't visible in the scroll pane when I press the TreeItem (TreeView automatically contains a scroll pane). So if I stretch the window so that less than 3 tree items are hidden, nothing will show. And it's not that the TableView gets shown at the wrong place, the problem is that the right tree item isn't selected (I know this because I've printed out the key value.

Here is a SSCCE that shows this bug. Select wrapper 1 in the table, and Wrapper 6 will be the selected one. If you change the size of the TreeView so that less than three TreeItems are hidden, nothing well get selected.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SSCCE extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AnchorPane rootLayout;
    private TreeView<Wrapper> overview; 

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("SSCCE");

        initRootLayout();
        showTreeView();
    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        rootLayout = new AnchorPane();
        rootLayout.setPrefSize(300, 200);

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }       

    ObservableList<String> columns = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Wrapper> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private void showTreeView() {

        // Dummy values
        columns.addAll("key", "text");              
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "test"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "test2"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("2", "test3"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("2", "test4"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("3", "test5"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("3", "test6"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("4", "test7"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("4", "test8"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("5", "test9"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("5", "test10"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("6", "test11"));
        data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList("6", "test12"));
        items.addAll(new Wrapper(1, "wrapper 1"), new Wrapper(2, "wrapper 2"), new Wrapper(3, "wrapper 3"), new Wrapper(4, "wrapper 4"), new Wrapper(5, "wrapper 5"), new Wrapper(6, "wrapper 6"));

        TreeItem<Wrapper> root = new TreeItem<Wrapper>();
        overview = new TreeView<Wrapper>(root);
        overview.setPrefHeight(75);

        overview.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Wrapper>, TreeCell<Wrapper>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Wrapper> call(TreeView<Wrapper> stringTreeView) {
                TreeCell<Wrapper> treeCell = new TreeCell<Wrapper>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Wrapper item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty || item == null) {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            if (getTreeItem().isLeaf() && isSelected()) {
                                setText(null);

                                // A debug text that proves that the wrong item is being selected.
                                System.out.println("Selected wrapper: " + item);

                                TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                                    final int j = i;

                                    TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(
                                            columns.get(i));

                                    column.setCellValueFactory((
                                            TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                                            param.getValue().get(j)
                                                    .toString()));

                                    table.getColumns()
                                            .add(column);
                                }

                                ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> selected_data = FXCollections
                                        .observableArrayList();

                                for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

                                    if(Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(0)) == item.getKey()) {
                                        selected_data.add(data.get(i));
                                    }
                                }
                                table.setItems(selected_data);

                                VBox vbox = new VBox(new Label(item
                                        .getValue()), table);
                                setGraphic(vbox);
                            } else {
                                setText(item.getValue());
                                setGraphic(null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                return treeCell;
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            TreeItem<Wrapper> target = new TreeItem<Wrapper>(items.get(i));
            root.getChildren().add(target);
        }

        overview.setShowRoot(false);
        rootLayout.getChildren().add(overview);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Wrapper {
    private int key;
    private String value;

    Wrapper(int key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Wrapper " + key;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the table will be shown up on the leaf nodes only, right? Should be the table hided again when the another tree item is selected? Why not to show a tableview just on side of treeview, like a master-detail view?

Comment: Yes. The table should be hidden again when another tree item is selected. Do you mean like two separated windows, where the left on shows the treeview and the right one shows the tableview, for example? This an option, in the same way that using a TreeTableView might be an option. But that will be a compromise in terms of design. But with that said: If I there is no way of implementing exactly what I want, I might have to compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Setting custom cell factory is not a way to go here. Because the cells are reused to render multiple items, so if initially all cells are visible within treeview's viewport, just default selection of an item will not trigger reusage of cell, thus no invocation on updateItem(). On the other hand, if  there are other items beyond the viewport and user scrolls down to them then the cell of the upper invisible item will be reused to render below ones which newly entered to viewport. This imo is the explanation of the behavior described in the comment below. In short, defining custom `TreeCell` is not correct approach, instead we can observe item selection changes and set graphic in there:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( ( ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<Wrapper>> observable,
        TreeItem<Wrapper> oldValue, TreeItem<Wrapper> newValue ) ->
        {
            System.out.println( "Selected newValue: " + newValue );

            if ( oldValue != null )
            {
                // hide graphic of previous selected item
                oldValue.setGraphic( null );
            }

            if ( newValue != null )
            {
                TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<>();
                for ( int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++ )
                {
                    final int j = i;

                    TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(
                            columns.get( i ) );

                    column.setCellValueFactory( (
                                    TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param ) -> 
                            new SimpleStringProperty( param.getValue().get( j ) ) );

                    table.getColumns().add( column );
                }

                ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> selected_data = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList();

                for ( int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++ )
                {
                    if ( Integer.parseInt( data.get( i ).get( 0 ) ) == newValue.getValue().getKey() )
                    {
                        selected_data.add( data.get( i ) );
                    }
                }
                table.setItems( selected_data );
                VBox vbox = new VBox( new Label( newValue.getValue().getValue() ), table );
                newValue.setGraphic( vbox );
            }
        } );
```

and **not** to set `treeView.setCellFactory(...)`. Now the problem is how to hide the item's text.

Comment: Thanks! But I get a lot of errors trying out this piece of code since E doesn't have the methods `setGraphics()` or `isSelected()`. Do I need to have E extending the TableCell interface or something like that, and then provide it with these methods?

Comment: E is your class defined in the question: TreeView<E> treeView = new TreeView<E>(rootItem);

Comment: Sorry, further assistance would be nice! The problem is that when I try to implement your example above, It says that TreeCell doesn't contain any `setGraphics()` method. Maybe you meant `setGraphic()`? It also says that the TreeItem class doesn't contain the `isSelected()` method, which it doesn't according to the Oracle documentiation.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka that's was my fault. Updated.

Comment: Okay now I kind of get the right result. Only problem is that when I press a TreeItem in the TreeView, the node that shows a TableView is the node that is two steps below the first node that isn't visible in the scroll pane when I press the TreeItem (TreeView automatically contains a scroll pane). So if I stretch the window so that less than 3 tree items are hidden, nothing will show. And it's not that the TableView gets shown at the wrong place, the problem is that the right tree item isn't selected (I know this because I've printed out the key value. Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: So when I press a certain TreeItem, the one that gets `isSelected() == true` is not the one I actually select, but instead the TreeItem that is two places below the first one that isn't visible. And if I stretch the window so that less than three items are hidden, it doesn't matter if I stretch it back. Nothing will show. Should we move this discussion to the chat btw?

Comment: Well @JonatanStenbacka at this stage it is more helpful if you provide MVCE (SSCCE) that demonstrates the problem described in your above comments. FYI, since the cells are reused to render the tree's items, it is important to pay attention on updateItem() code.

Comment: Okay. I have added an SSCCE above! It demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka using setCellFactory(...) was wrong approach. instead try to use selectedItem change listener. But it has a problem where in the listener you cannot change the item text directly.